# Efficient method to mathematically convolve 2d arrays without padding

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, convolution

For odd integers T and S, Array1 and Array2 are both 2 dimensional ndarrays of shape (T, S) which represent samples of functions func1(t, s) and func2(t, s) on an equally spaced lattice L of T x S points stretching from t=0 to t=1 and s=-10 to s=10. I wish to obtain a third Array3 of shape (T, S) which takes values as func3(t, s) on this lattice, where func3(t, s) is the sum of func1(q, p)*func2(t-q, s-p) over all q and p such that both (q, p) and (t-q, s-p) are on the lattice L.

My current working method for doing this is padding Array2 with 0's to create an ExtendedArray2 of shape (2T-1, 2S-1) such that ExtendedArray2[(T-1)+x][(S-1)+y]=Array2[x][y] for 0 <= x <= T-1 and 0 <= y <= S-1, and takes values of 0 elsewhere. I convolve Array1 and ExtendedArray2 in the following way using signal from scipy to get my desired result.

```
Array3 = signal.fftconvolve(Array1, ExtendedArray2, mode='valid')
```

The fftconvolve is reasonably fast, but this method has the drawback that it requires doubling both dimensions of the input arrays, which makes the speed take a hit compared to what it could be  on the smaller sized arrays. Is there a way a speed-efficient convolution method could be used on the unpadded arrays to obtain Array3?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no faster method of computing this than what you are doing, unless there are specific properties of the functions to be exploited (e.g. if one of the functions is separable).

You can write faster code, though. For example, you could use the FFTW library instead of the FFT in SciPy. You should also ensure that `ExtendedArray2` is of an easy size to apply the FFT to (i.e. a product of small integers). Instead of choosing the shape (2T-1, 2S-1), make it a bit larger, shape (2T-1+n, 2S-1+m), choosing non-negative n and m so that 2T-1+n and 2S-1+m are both a product of, for example, 2s, 3s and 5s.

Comment: Could you point me out benchmarks that support the idea that FFTW would perform better? What I found does not give this dramatic difference[(1)](https://notebook.community/abigailStev/whizzy_scripts/fft_comparison)

Comment: @Bob I’m not sure what kind of difference you were expecting. That page you linked shows, for the 2D case, FFTW being ~15% faster than fftpack, [which is deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html), and ~2x as fast as NumPy. And this is for the case of a nice power of two size array. For “awkward” sizes (where you don’t have a multiple of small integers) the difference can easily be one or two orders of magnitude over other implementations.

Comment: Well, you are right about the benchmark using a smooth FFT size. But the resultsI read in the linked document was `SciPy, FFT, 2D:
10 loops, best of 3: 17.2 ms per loop` and `pyFFTW, FFT, 2D:
10 loops, best of 3: 26.5 ms per loop`, in favor of SciPy. I read somewhere else that `pyFFTW` could be 3 times faster, but if that's the case, why don't sicpy/numpy simply use it instead of fftpack?

Comment: @Bob FFTW has a GPL license, meaning that if you use it, you can only distribute your code as GPL also. That's off-putting to many. I looked at the timings at the bottom, it seems those are IFFTs. The IFFT is exactly the same as the FFT, it makes no sense for the timings to be different. There's something fishy about these comparisons. Somehow I can't install pyfftw on my machine (M1 Mac), even when installing from source there are pip errors, so I can't run these comparisons myself. But two years ago I compared FFTW to the FFT in OpenCV, and found a ~100x difference for a prime-sized array.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you described I would simply use

```py
Array3 = signal.fftconvolve(Array1, Array2, mode='full')
```

It will calculate the a fast length for you (checking the code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4cf21e753cf937d1c6c2d2a0e372fbc1dbbeea81/scipy/signal/_signaltools.py#L667))

Could you compare and let us know the run times you see.